# REGEX sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i run this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT email FROM `users` WHERE `email` REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+(@outlook.com)$' and email NOT LIKE '%sex%' and email NOT LIKE '.%' and email NOT LIKE '-%' or email LIKE '%@live.com' AND userid > 10000 AND email NOT LIKE '%sex%' AND email NOT LIKE '%+%' and email NOT LIKE '.%' and email NOT LIKE '-%'
```

and my problem is, in the row results i get invaild email address with the domain @live.com
for example this result : "a**執**b@live.com".
vaild email dont have a chinese characters.
how do i ignore/filter the invalid characters in the mail results?
i changed my query to this:

```
REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+(@outlook.com|@live.com)
```

but the problem is, i get emails of @outlook.com which their userid is over 10000.
so i deleted the "userid > 10000"
and now the problem is i get emails of @live.com which their userid is under 10000
what i suppose to do??
thank you

Comment: how is ther userid related to the email being registered on outlook.com vs live.com?

Comment: Do your regexp manipulation in the higher level language?

Comment: anyway, how about this query `WHERE (\`email\` REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+(@outlook.com)$' AND userid<10000) OR (\`email\` REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+(@live.com)$' AND userid>=10000)` ??

Answer (score 0):

You only add a $ at the end of the REGEX. In the sample you can see what is the result of your REGEX

**sample**

```
MariaDB []> SELECT *, b REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+(@outlook.com|@live.com)$'  as result  FROM abc ;
+----+--------------------+--------+
| id | b                  | result |
+----+--------------------+--------+
| 38 | asd888@outlook.co  |      0 |
| 47 | asd888@outlook.com |      1 |
| 48 | hallo@outlook.com  |      1 |
| 49 | a執b@live.com      |      0 |
| 50 | aaaa@live.com      |      1 |
+----+--------------------+--------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB []>
```